How to exclude Private members while generating Doxygen
I am trying to use Doxygen and Sphinx to generate documentation for some code. Both are running successfully, and the HTML is generated, but the HTML includes all the private members of the classes. Is it possible to exclude the private members and include only the private functions.
My Doxyfile has these configurations:
EXTRACT_ALL            = NO
EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = YES
EXTRACT_PRIV_VIRTUAL   = YES
EXTRACT_PACKAGE        = NO
EXTRACT_STATIC         = NO
EXTRACT_LOCAL_CLASSES  = YES
EXTRACT_LOCAL_METHODS  = NO

The api.rst file is
.. doxygenindex:: 
   :project: <ProjectName>

Index.rst
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:


   api

I have tried changing the Doxyfile to exclude all private members which did not work. Also tried excluding it in the conf.py of the sphinx project which also failed.

What exactly did you try? Did you set EXTRACT_PRIVATE = NO? What "did not work"? Please [edit] and be specific.

Which version of doxygen are you using? In doxygen the EXTRACT_PRIVATE operates on methods and members, so no distinction possible. Does Sphinx use the xml output from doxygen? (otherwise also have a look at breathe) in the xml output always the private members and methods are shown but in the Sphinx / braeathe processing it might be possible to distinguish.

@albert yes I am using xml output from Doxygen in sphinx. I'll look into sphinx and breathe for now. It would be great if you could share some references.

I don't use Sphinx / Breathe so I cannot advise.

@albert I have solved it using breathe. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

The private members (variables) are hidden after changing the api.rst file to
.. doxygenclass:: <class1 name>
    :project: project
.. doxygenclass:: <class2 name>
    :project: project

